# Translating c++ to MIPS assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, mips

I'm trying to convert the following line of C++ code to MIPS assembly:

```
cout << a2[i]
```

This is the code I've tried but I'm getting incorrect results.

*The variable i is saved in $t5.

```
li $v0, 1
la $a0, a2
sll $t5, $t5, 2
add $a0, $a0, $t5
srl $t5, $t5, 2
lw $a0, 0($a0)
syscall
```

Comment: what platform are you coding for? what's the type of `a2`? is the indexing operator overloaded?

Comment: Have you considered compiling the code and examining the output?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little rusty when it comes to MIPS. However, I do remember some things.

You generally shouldn't use the $a registers unless you're passing arguments to a function (as you do with syscall).

So, in these two cases, I would use temporary registers instead:

```
la $a0, a2
add $a0, $a0, $t5
```

becomes

```
la $t0, a2
add $t1, $t0, $t5
```

and then:

```
lw $a0, 0($t1)
syscall
```

And you can probably omit this as well:

```
srl $t5, $t5, 2
```

Other than that, I would ask what sort of incorrect output are you receiving?